# applying dotfiles after forking someone else's dotfiles github repo

Tags: git, dotfiles

I'm trying to manage my dotfile using git and found a good dotfile repo to use as a basis in https://mths.be/dotfiles.
So I forked the https://mths.be/dotfiles repo to my github account. I'm trying to apply the dotfiles using symlinks to my home directory, but I can't seem to be able to do it.

I've done everything until "set -- -f; source bootstrap.sh" according to the read me file in https://mths.be/dotfiles. But I'm stuck and can't find a solution out of this. Apparently the bootstrap.sh doesn't seem to work properly neither.

Basically, to sum up, my questions are (as a newbie to github and managing dotfiles):

How do you apply the dotfiles in an another directory other than the home directory? (I hear you can use symlinks to do that...but how exactly?

There seems to be a problem in line 13 in https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/bootstrap.sh (if [ "$1" == "--force" -o "$1" == "-f" ]; then). When I try to source the bootstrap.sh, it says = not found. What's wrong?

What is the role of bootstrap.sh exactly?

Many thanks.

Below is the bootstrap.sh code

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE}")";

git pull origin master;

function doIt() {
    rsync --exclude ".git/" --exclude ".DS_Store" --exclude ".osx" \
    --exclude "bootstrap.sh" --exclude "README.md" --exclude "LICENSE-MIT.txt" -avh --no-perms . ~;
    source ~/.bash_profile;
}

if [ "$1" == "--force" -o "$1" == "-f" ]; then
    doIt;
else
    read -p "This may overwrite existing files in your home directory. Are you sure? (y/n) " -n 1;
    echo "";
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
        doIt;
    fi;
fi;
unset doIt;
```

Comment: Could you show us the output of `echo $0` please? The result could maybe explain why line 13 is not working. What do you mean by **apply** dotfiles? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AnimiVulpis The output of echo $0 is "-zsh". Applying the dotfiles means...well Iknow the dotfiles should be in the home folder. But here I'm trying to manage the dotfiles in a separate directory in ~home/projects/dotfiles. I want to keep them in the projects/dotfiles directory as I'm going to use this directory as my github local repo. 

I think I should symlink the files in the local repo to the dotfiles in home directory OR at lease should copy the local repo files into the home directory. Am I right?

Comment: Which part of the provided **dotfiles** repo are you planning to use? Because there are a lot of different configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using `zsh` but the dotfiles repo you mention is not using `zsh` (you can see this by the absence of a `.zshrc` file)

---

To use specific configurations you link those files (and the folders these configurations use) into your home folder. For example `.vimrc`

```
$ cd ~
$ ln -s /path/to/dotfiles/.vimrc .vimrc
$ ln -s /path/to/dotfiles/.vim .vim
```

First command will change directory into your home folder.

Second command will create a symbolic link from the dotfiles repo `.vimrc` into your home folder

Third command will link the the `.vim` folder (used in `.vimrc`) into your home folder

---

To answer the **third part** of your question first (because the first two are yet to clarify) I will cite the [`README.md`](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles#using-git-and-the-bootstrap-script)

> The bootstrapper script will pull in the latest version and copy the files to your home folder.

*I will add the other answers as they become more clear*

Comment: I've run the bootstrapper script but it doesn't seem to copy the files to my home folder. :(